# How to use querySelectorAll to select classes in a section div rather than the whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say I have the following code:

```
let testA = document.querySelectorAll('.vehicle')
```

Let say I have this html

```
<div class="vehicle">
// some stuff
</div>

<div class="vehicle">
// some stuff
</div>
```

I know `querySelectorAll` will select all the classes on the page but is there a way to use `querySelectorAll` to just select the items from the `first vehicle div` class to do something. Then use querySelectorAll from the `second vehicle div class` to do something?

Comment: You can find the "vehicle" `<div>` you're interested, and then use `.querySelectorAll()` from that element (instead of from `document`).

Comment: @Pointy Sorry I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: The `.querySelectorAll()` method can be used from any element in the DOM, and it looks "down" the DOM tree. When you call it from `document`, it searches the entire DOM. So you can find any element you want, however is appropriate, and then to search the document inside that element just call `.querySelectorAll()` from the element (`yourElement.querySelectorAll(".whatever")`)

Comment: Of course, if your containers really are distinct in some way, they should have additional classes to make them easier to find.

Comment: @Pointy so confused. Is there an example of this?

Comment: `Is there an example of this?`[yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like that**

```
const vehicleElementsList = document.querySelectorAll('.vehicle');

vehicleElementsList.forEach((vehicle, index) => {
  
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
     // some stuff
    break;
    
    case 1:
    // some stuff
    break;
    
    default:
    // some stuff
    break;
  }
  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can achieve this by using the :nth-child()

let firstVehicleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.vehicle:nth-child(1)');

let secondVehicleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.vehicle:nth-child(2)');
You can adjust the nth-child() index according to the position of the .vehicle elements within their parent container.

Comment: This is not a good solution because what if I have 50 divs with the same class name on the page? I can't keep doing `nth-child(1)...nth-child(2)..etc`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
const myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".vehicle");
```

The elements in the NodeList can be accessed by an index number.
To access the second  node you can write:
myNodeList[1];

Comment: what if I have 50 nodes? This wouldn't be a good solution then right?

Comment: you can have n no of nodes. you can call the const once and access your desired node just using myNodeList(n-1);